# Update all columns LIKE 'field' to NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that has: 
ID,Name,RefNumber and then: -

```
Field1,
Field2,
Field3,
Field4,
Field5,
etc up to 150
```

When I update with new info in field 1, field2, I want all the rest of the fields to be made empty or NULL, as they have no meaning now.

I cant name them all (as new ones are added all the time) but instead want to use a statement like : -
Where the column contains the letters 'Field' set it to "".
Can this be done?

Else how can I blank all columns except 3 specific ones.

Comment: Why do you have a table where you are adding new columns all the time?  You have a problem with your data structure.

Comment: Blank string `!==` NULL!

Comment: @GordonLinoff  When we add new functionality it may have 50 editable fields, and each field has different usage depending on the tag given. So want to clear old data before new data goes in, bot not delete everything.....and do not want to write a statement that has 100 fields in.